# ...(,) не сломав их?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

`Сможете составить цифру 6 из спичек(,) не сломав их.`

Нужна запятая? Нет? Оба?

Comment: Не нужна, кроме разве что риторической паузы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Правильно:**

(1)  *Сможете составить цифру 6 из **спИчек,** / **не сломАв их?***

Деепричастный оборот обособляется, нет перехода в наречие. **Два ударения:** на сказуемом и на обороте.

**Сравнить:**

(2) Сможете составить цифру 6 из **спичек** / **их не сломАв?**

В этом варианте на деепричастие падает **ударение**, соответственно, оборот не обособляется.

Comment: А если тесно связан со сказуемым? Если его не так-то просто опустить? Кстати, и в том и вто варианте так-то ударение на деепричастие падает.

Comment: Максим, я даю вам решение для вашего конкретного варианта. Просто произнесите две фразы, а на схему не смотрите. Есть межд ними разница?

Comment: Разница в чëм? И может всë-таки оборот не обособляттся именно в моëм примере (без переставления).?

Comment: Не может.   Вы можете поставить ударение в конце оборота на "их"?

Comment: А почему не может быть частью сказуемого?

Comment: Какого сказуемого? СГС, СИС?

Comment: Что такое СГС и СИС?

Comment: Составное именное или глагольное сказуемое. Там структура строго расписана.  Для СИС связка "быть" и ее эквиваленты. Например: Я был как во сне.

Comment: А здесь разве не глагольное? (_Сможете составить_.)

Comment: Да, это СГС, а дальше вы что предлагаете? Про какую часть сказуемого говорите?  Здесь можно говорить только о тесной связи обстоятельства со сказуемым.

Comment: _Сможете составить не сломав их_. Не сказуемое? И может быть сказуемым? И если не может, почему?

Comment: В глагольное сказуемое входит только глагол.  Учебник, стр. 69 – 71 https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf